# in ionic and html how to access attribute by composited name

Tags: html, ionic2

I want to show my button with the background-color in my object called ".color".

```
{{act.color}}
```

appears as "#ff00ff" and works fine and

```
style="background-color:#ff00ff"
```

works also.
But the highlighted code causes an error.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ion-item *ngFor="let act of questions.qs; let i = index">
    {{act.quote}}
    {{act.color}}
    <div [ngSwitch]="act.type">
      <div *ngSwitchCase="'1to10'">
        <button large ion-button style="background-color:#ff00ff">1</button>
        **<button large ion-button style="background-color:"+{{act.color}}>2</button>**
        <button large ion-button>2</button>
        <button large ion-button>3</button>
...
```

The error is

> Error in ./CreateSinglePermPage class CreateSinglePermPage - caused by: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '+{{act.color}}' is not a valid attribute name.

How do I access my color value from my object in html?

Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set background color dynamically like below

```
 <button large ion-button [style.background-color]="act.color">2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]` when you are binding a variable from component.

Also `background-color` has a hyphen and so you will need single quotes.

Try:

```
<button large ion-button [style]="'background-color':act.color">2</button>
```